# How to connect a Win XP PC and Win 7 PC with a Linksys WRT54G Router to a PPPOE connection?

Tags: router

I have two PCs and a WRT56G Router. My provider is a PPPOE connection (username and password). I can connect my Windows 7 easily. Even if I choose Auto or PPPOE on the router's configuration. Maybe because this one had the connection in the first place with the username and password set up.

But I can't connect the Windows XP PC. Actually it does connect in a way, but it receives and sents just a few packages. I can actually see in My Network Places how many packages does the Gateway make and it's a big difference. And it won't open any page.

How should I set up the router so I can give enough bandwith to the Windows XP PC ?

I've seen another problem that I forgot to mention. The router can't connect with the pppoe settings. I don't know why, but with Auto DHCP setting and my Windows 7 connected with pppoe settings works.

EDIT2:

I've installed Win 7 on the other PC so I won't have any problem of compatibility betwen them. But I still can't connect the router with PPPOE settings to the internet. It looks like this: http://img641.imageshack.us/img641/9780/capturefba.png

If you need any other screens or info, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you contacted your ISP for configuration assistance? Linksys is a popular brand, so they probably have configuration recommendations - unless for some odd reason it is against their AUP.